# do I have to join, or is there some lookup function when running regressions?

Tags: r

So, I have a data management question. I have a file (represented in the dummy data below as df_time) which has information about an ID that changes at specific points in time (in the dummy T1, T2). I want to do regressions on whether something is different compared to a reference time (T1). I also need to match this to census information for the regressions. Dummy data is:

```
ID = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
T1_class = c("safe", "safe", "unsafe", "unsafe", "safe")
T1_census = c("001", "002", "003", "004", "005")
T2_class = c("safe", "unsafe", "unsafe", "safe", "safe")
T2_census = c("001", "003", "009", "007", "001")
T2_change = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1)

df_time <- data.frame(ID, T1_class, T1_census, T2_class, T2_census, T2_change)
df_time


census_id = c("001", "002", "003", "004", "005", "006", "007", "008", "009")
a_variable = c(1, 20, 4, 19, 6, 56, 67, 12, 52)
b_variable = c(12, 10, 9, 10, 3, 20, 12, 8, 2)

df_census <- data.frame(census_id, a_variable, b_variable)
df_census
```

Because the actual data has tons of census information and many more points in time, I really would rather not left_join it to each of the points in time, because this would add over 200 variables. I.e. I'd rather not do:

```
df_combined <- left_join(df_time, df_census, by = c("T1_census" = "census_id")
df_combined <- left_join(df_time, df_census, by = c("T2_census" = "census_id")
```

I want to know if it's possible to look it up as it goes, so I'm only temporarily joining the values I need for a given regression.

I want to be able to run something like this:

```
mylogit <- glm(T3_change ~ T1_class + a_variable , data = df_time & df_census, family = "binomial")
```

Where, basically, it looks up the T1_census code in df_time, and then pulls the matching a_variable from df_census. Is that possible? Or should I just join it?

Comment: The column name showed in the example is `T2_change`

Comment: If you have huge data I'd suggest to use data.table instead of data.frame. It's way faster and the joins shouldn't be a problem. Use `merge(dt_a, dt_b on.x="a", on.y="b")` instead of left join. The merge version from data.table is quite similar to base R functions, but also way faster.